# Handling CodeIgniter form validation (rule keys and data types)

Tags: codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

Okay, so I've been searching for a while this question, but couldn't find an answer (or at least some direct one) that explains this to me.

I've been using CodeIgniter 3.x Form Validation library, so I have some data like this:

```
// Just example data
$input_data = [
    'id'        => 1,
    'logged_in' => TRUE,
    'username'  => 'alejandroivan'
];
```

Then, when I want to validate it, I use:

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($input_data);
$this->form_validation->set_rules([
    [
        'field'    => 'id',
        'label'    => 'The ID to work on',
        'rules'    => 'required|min_length[1]|is_natural_no_zero'
    ],
    [
        'field'    => 'username',
        'label'    => 'The username',
        'rules'    => 'required|min_length[1]|alpha_numeric|strtolower'
    ],
    [
        'field'    => 'logged_in',
        'label'    => 'The login status of the user',
        'rules'    => 'required|in_list[0,1]'
    ]
]);

if ( $this->form_validation->run() === FALSE ) { /* failed */ }
```

So I have some questions here:

- Is the `label` key really necessary? I'm not using the Form Validation auto-generated error messages in any way, I just want to know if the data passed validation or not. Will something else fail if I just omit it? As this will be a JSON API, I don't really want to print the description of the field, just a static error that I have already defined.
- In the `username` field of my example, will the `required` rule check length? In other words, is `min_length` optional in this case? The same question for `alpha_numeric`... is the empty string considered alpha numeric?
- In the `logged_in` field (which is boolean), how do I check for `TRUE` or `FALSE`? Would `in_list[0,1]` be sufficient? Should I include `required` too? Is there something like `is_boolean`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would also point out that, if you are so inclined, you can easily extend the form_validation library and add an is_boolean rule. That's not actually a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The "label" key is necessary, but it can be empty.
2. The "required" rule does not check length, nor does the "alpha_numeric". It checks that a value is present, it does not check the length of said value. For that, there is min_length[] and max_length[].
3. If you're only passing a 0 or 1, then this is probably the easiest and shortest route.